# Adding more contacts in a Sendgrid list

Tags: python, email, sendgrid

I have created a new list using Sendgrid's Python module, but I am confused about how to add emails to that list using the API. According to Sendgrid's [documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#Add-a-Single-Recipient-to-a-List-POST) I have to send a POST request with parameters 'list_id' and 'recipient_id.' What I don't understand is, where am I going to find this recipient_id when I am trying to add the email addresses for the first time?

I was successful in adding single recipients following this [documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#List-Recipients-GET) and code example from [Github](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/examples/contactdb/contactdb.py):

```
response = sg.client.contactdb.recipients.post(request_body=[{'email': 'test@email.com'}])
```

This adds the email address to what seems to be a full list of email addresses ever saved in my Sendgrid account. I am probably facing this problem because I am new to using APIs, although the documentation is really very poor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recipients are separate from lists, because they can belong to many lists or segments. Before you can add the recipients to the list, you need to create the recipients. You can do this with a request like `POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/recipients`. The response body will contain the recipient IDs. You can find more details via the [SendGrid docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#Add-Recipients-POST).

Please let me know what we can improve about these docs and I'll make sure it gets to the product team.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I have noticed how you broke down each and every sort of interactions(I am not sure what it's really called) into separate API requests. I guess this is very helpful at times. It would have been a plus if there were sections where this sort of step-by-step procedures(add recipients first, then to a segment or list) were mentioned.

Comment: Hello Sendgrid,
 I think for convenience purposes, you should allow a recipient to be added directly to a list. I'm also trying to add recipients to a list and I have to  save them with the above endpoint, get the id before I can subscribe the email to the targetted list. You can handle the one to many relationships at your backend while we focus on adding recipients to their respective lists.
Thanks you.